# How to compare a percentage of a sample to an observed population percentage, similar to chisquare

Tags: chi-squared-test

I have a sample that is randomly drawn from a population, and want to test if the distribution for a categorical variable age (under 30, 30-64, and 65+) is significantly different from observed population age percentages. Is there a way to compare the percentage in each of those categories in the sample to the overall population percentages for the same age category. The population includes the sample, so this is why I'm running into issues conducting a chi square test of the age categories by an indicator for in the sample or not.

Thoughts?

Comment: Construct the $3\times 2$ table of counts within and without your sample.  I believe this is a faq, so consider searching for similar questions.

Comment: To add to whuber's comment: you get counts without simply by subtracting your sample from your population.